# Elastic Collision Between Two Objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elastic Collision And Momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44629/elastic-collision-and-momentum)

I've already asked this question, [Elastic Collision And Momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44629/elastic-collision-and-momentum), but I didn't find the answer particularly helpful--sorry, I don't mean to be rude.

So, here is my newest attempt for this problem:

Before the collision, $m_1$ possesses kinetic energy, which it gained by having its potential energy convert to it as it fell $h$. On the other hand, $m_2$ has no kinetic energy energy before the collision. After the collision, some of $m_1$'s kinetic energy is transferred into $m_2$, which is why it doesn't return to its original height.

Energy Analysis:

$m_1:$ $KE_i=mgh=244.02~J$; $KE_f=\frac{1}{2}mv^2_{f,1}$

$m_2:$ $KE_i=0~J$; $KE_f\frac{1}{2}mv^2_{f,2}$

Velocity of $m_1$ before collision: $\frac{1}{2}mv^2_{i,1}=mgh~\rightarrow v_{i,1}=9.90~m/s$

Momentum Analysis:

$m_1:$ $\vec{p}=(4.98)(9.90)$; $\vec{p}=4.98\vec{v}_{f,1}$

$m_2:$ $\vec{p}_{i,2}=0$; $\vec{p}_{f,2}=9.40\vec{v}_{f,2}$

This is where I get stuck. I have been working on this problem for quite some time, I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: You don't re-ask question to get more attention for them. You edit the original and consider [offering a bounty](http://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) if you have the reputation.

Comment: Sorry, I did edit my post, and I don't have the capabilities, yet, to offer a bounty. This took me so long to type.